# Find black a pixel position in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

i want to find black pixel positions and save them. i used this code.

```
I= imread('bin_ecgm.png');

 imshow(I);

  [r c] =size(I);

   for j=1:c

    for i=1:r

        if(I(i,j)==1)
        [i j]    
        end
    end
end
```

how to store black pixel positions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

usually black pixels are `I( ii, jj ) == 0`... you can do that without a loop

```
[ii jj] = find( I == 0 ); % or I == 1 if you insist...
```

PS,
It is best [not to use `i` and `j` as variable names in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab).

Comment: how to save this pixel vaues

Comment: @user2120268 The positions of the black pixels will be in the matrix `[ii jj]`. If you're asking how to save the pixel coordinates to a file, you could use `dlmwrite('filename.txt', [ii jj])`.